# printing wrong character from file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, char

I'm trying to print the first character of each line, but for some reason my code prints the second element of each line?

My code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    char c;
    char array[150];
    file = fopen("/Users/bqas/Desktop/m/m/dict", "r");
    while((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF){
        fgets(array, 150, file);
        printf("%c",array[0]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

some of text line;

```
a   un, uno, una[Article]
aardvark    cerdo hormiguero
aardvark    oso hormiguero[Noun]
aardvarks   cerdos hormigueros
aardvarks   osos hormigueros
```

Comment: that's expected: `while((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF){` consumes 1 character at the start of each line...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a text file line by line and retrieve the content of each line in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200822/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-and-retrieve-the-content-of-each-line-in-c)

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 150.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this code:

```
while((c=fgetc(file))!= EOF){
    fgets(array, 150, file);
    printf("%c",array[0]);
```

the expression: `c=fgetc(file)`  is reading the first character of each line and sticking it into the variable `c`

But the call to `printf()` is printing the first char of the array[] and not the first char that is in `c`.

suggest using:

```
while(fgets(array, 150, file))
{
    printf("%c",array[0]);
```